# Is there any equivalent of python's inspect.getargspec in javascript/node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, inspect

I want to get a list of argument names of `Function`, for example:

```
var f = (a, b, c) => console.log(a, b, c);
var [fargs] = something.like.inspect.getargspec(f);
console.log(fargs); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: look here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Take a look at how AngularJS parses function declarations to get args, it might be of use, for a solution that works on most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Node and want the argument names, check out the `introspect` NPM module:

```
> var introspect = require('introspect')
> var f = (a, b, c) => console.log(a, b, c);
> console.log(introspect(f))
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```